# Does Facebook support multiple callback urls?

Tags: facebook, callback, scalability

I work at a large Facebook game developer and we're trying to decide the best way to scale our infrastructure. Our callback URL is not using round robin DNS so it is a single point of failure. We have a VIP setup to mitigate the damage but this is still not ideal.

Before we go down the route of implementing round robin dns, I was wondering if there's a way to have Facebook randomly choose from a set of callback URLs. This seems like it would be a trivial thing for Facebook to implement and would save its developers a lot of time and money and provide a better user experience.

Comment: You could pass a random callback then

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to specify multiple.  I would suggest making sure your VIP load-balancer solution is robust.